# Check if a CSS class exists without jQuery

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

Using vanilla javascript or prototype can someone show me how I could run a check to see if a class exists?  For example I am adding a class called hideIt with this code :

```
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay_modal");
overlay.className += " hideIt";
```

I also need a script that later can check to see if hideIt exists.  I have tried things like :

```
if (overlay.className == "hideIt")
```

But that is no good.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [regexp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). `\b` will match word boundaries (a space, a newline character, punctuation character or end of string).

```
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay_modal");
if (overlay.className.match(/\bhideIt\b/)) 
{
    // frob a widget
}
```

Comment: Best, cleanest and most widely supported answer! :)

Answer (score 6):

You could use `getElementsByClassName()`, albeit this isn't supported in *all* browsers (not in IE < 9):

```
if (!document.getElementsByClassName('classname').length){
    // class name does not exist in the document
}

else {
    // class exists in the document
}
```

You could, depending on browser compatibility requirements, use `querySelectorAll()`:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('#overlay_modal.hideIt')) {
    // the element with id of overlay_modal exists and has the class-name 'hideIt'
}
```

References:

- [Compatibility for `querySelectorAll` at Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t13).
- [`querySelectorAll()` at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll).
- [`getElementsByClassName()` at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.getElementsByClassName).
- [Compatibility for getElementsByClassName(), at Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t11).

Comment: I still think [using a regexp on the element's `className`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8405435/139010) is the best approach in this case, since they already have a reference to the element itself. Works in all browsers, no feature detection or shims needed.

Comment: I tend to agree, but since you'd already covered that angle it didn't seem right including that aspect in my own answer. I wasn't saying that either of these are the *best* ways, but instead presenting alternatives to those already posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
var id = document.getElementById("id");
var classes = id.className.split(" ");
if(classes.indexOf("class_name") == -1)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because the question asks for it here also is [the Prototype way](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/hasClassName/),

```
if (overlay.hasClassName('hideIt'))
```